# laravel url ../public/login not working but ../public/index.php/login works without bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, indexing, public

i'm using laravel to make my website.
after i upload my web files on my sub-domain : rivelapark.com/au
i can't access rivelapark.com/au/public/login
(*in my local server, localhost/au/public/login did works)

But, when i access rivelapark.com/au/public/index.php/login it works but my bootstrap is not working.

Here is my app>config>database.php:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'rivelapark.com',
            'database'  => '******',
            'username'  => '********',
            'password'  => '*******',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

and this is my public>.htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is there anyone could help ? Thank You Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls

> If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the mod_rewrite module.
>   If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Did you try to use this example?
mod_rewrite module is enabled?

Comment: Actually the main problem is the cache of the browser not yet refreshed. After waiting 15 minutes, now it works !

Answer (score 0):

Actually the main problem is the cache of the browser not yet refreshed. After waiting 15 minutes, now it works !