# Laravel public/index.php displays as plain text

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, apache2

I just installed an existing Laravel project onto a web server by git cloning. I have done as much proper setup as possible as per Laravel guidelines, including setting up Apache Virtual Hosts like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html/project/public">
       AllowOverride all
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /var/www/project/public
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also set up directory ownership / file permissions to the best of my ability. However, when visiting the website, the contents of public/index.php are displayed instead of the website being loaded. I know this has certainly been addressed somewhere before, and I apologize if that's the case, but I haven't been able to find clear answers. Much appreciated.

Other things I have done:

- installed php (it came loaded with the server and is version 5.5.9)
- a2enmod rewrite
- service apache2 reload
- [modification of .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290673/laravel-url-public-login-not-working-but-public-index-php-login-works-with)
- ensured the loaded page is not a cached one

Resources used:

- [How To Install Laravel 5 Framework on Ubuntu 15.10, 14.04, 12.04 & LinuxMint](http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/)
- [How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This command fixed my problem:

```
apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

I suppose that this is a duplicate question because it is php related, but this may be helpful to keep around as it is in the context of Laravel.

Comment: for php7 i used `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt`
thank you for the solution btw, it took me 5 hours of research to find you

Comment: For specific versions do: `sudo apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-phpVERSION`, replace version with specific php version your project requires i.e. `libapache2-mod-php7.4`. Apache will auto run `a2enmod php7.4` after install.

Answer (score 1):

The command:

`a2enmod php7.2`

did it for me.